# Send a NSString with \0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, special-characters, uint

I am trying to send a string terminated with \0 to a tcp socket but it seems the \0 does never reach its destination.

Using this code:

```
NSString* s=@"<b/> \0_";

uint8_t *buf = (uint8_t *)[s UTF8String];

int resCode = [outputStream write:buf maxLength:strlen((char *)buf)];
```

I only seem to send `@"<b/> "`. Probably the `\0` is seen as the end of the `uint8_t`.

Can someone tell me how it should be done??

Comment: Don't use an NSString to send data.  Use NSData or a buffer of bytes.

Comment: You should really check out some information how strings work. Especially how strings are escaped, then you will know why strlen doesn't return the valid length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it sends it without \0. `strlen` will return you length of the string, not counting null-terminators. Change it to something like

`[outputStream write:buf maxLength:(strlen((char *)buf) + 1)]`

Comment: You could add that the problem has got nothing to do with the `NSString` class, but only with the understanding of C`s string functions. Also, it's not necessary to terminate the NSString with the NUL character, that's done by `UTF8String`.

Comment: The \0 character is not used to terminate a NSString, but to terminate a commando at the server.

@sha: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm =)

Comment: @dkk I understand, but since `UTF8String` returns a null terminated C string, you don't have to add that character in the `NSString`.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to send ']0] character in your String.....

Can't you use any other character...because '\0' character is always treated as terminating character!

And if you really want to send it that way then send a different character and map it to '\0' when you receiv it!

Comment: I can't, because the receiver has already been implemented that way. And it is being used with other applications.

Comment: It's perfectly fine and common to use \0 as a terminating character in string io.